# Read EXIF/IPTC information from image in Cocoa

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, exif, iptc

I am unable to find any recent example on how to read EXIF/IPTC information from an image in Cocoa. Is there anything that can be easily done or should I use an external tool as exiftool and start it with NSTask ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Image Source functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) from the Image IO library. Something like...

```
CGImageSourceCreateWithData(someCFDataRef, nil);
CFDictionaryRef dictRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSource, 0, nil);
```

should fill `dictRef` with the EXIF data.

Answer (score 5):

There's some code that appears useful here: http://devmacosx.blogspot.com/2011/07/nsimage-exif-metadata.html